# How to create CDN in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn

I'm trying to deliver a file via CDN.I created a Blob and uploaded the file to it.
Now i want to use a CDN to deliver it as per Azure docs here http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/other/cdn/

> In the Windows Azure Management Portal, in the navigation pane, click
>   CDN.
>
> On the ribbon, click New. In the New dialog, select App Services, then
>   CDN, then Quick Create.

The problem is in my account there is nothing called App Services 
How am i supposed to create the CDN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are new to Azure (you created your account recently) you will not see CDN in the portal. Currently CDN is only enabled for customers who have used it before (~2-3 years). But I do believe we will very soon see CDN enabled for all customers.

And `Application Services` is a group which you will see when you click the big  plus (+) sign at the bottom left of management portal.

Comment: My only need for Azure now is to deliver the payload

Comment: This is great to know, thank you for making it clear. Azure appears to have it documented as if it's available for all users, but doesn't mention that it just might not exist for some: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/cdn/

Comment: ti was available for all users as preview few years ago. It was then "not ported" to the new portal when the management portal migrated from Silverlight (yeah, there was a Silverlight management portal for Windows Azure) to HTML5. And my firm believe is that this feature will pop up soon again.

Answer (score 10):

Azure CDN is available as of April 3, 2014, as announced at the //build conference (pricing is available [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/)).

You'll find CDN on the left-side along with the other services:

[image]

When you choose to add the endpoint, you can select from your storage accounts (or cloud services):

[image]

You'll then see your CDN endpoint, ready for use:

[image]

Comment: Great to know that.Thanks for posting the screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Astaykov is correct, access to CDN is being limited. It might be worth contacting MS support by submitting a ticket through the management portal to see whether CDN could be added to your subscription.