# Azure CDN for blob storage in new portal?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, cdn, azure-cdn

### Summary

Where can I create a CDN endpoint in the Windows Azure portal?

### Details / Background

I found this [great video from Scott Hanselman on getting set up with an Azure CDN](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingVideoMovingMyWebsitesImagesToTheAzureCDNAndUsingACustomDomain.aspx) (thanks, Scott!)

The video walks through creating a CDN endpoint for the storage. Unfortunately, at the time, CDNs were managed in the [old portal](https://windows.azure.com/) (now defunct).

I assumed that Azure would have moved this functionality to the new portal, so I found [this Microsoft article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/cdn/) on how to create a CDN endpoint. It reads:

> To create a new CDN endpoint for your storage account:
>
> In the Windows Azure Management Portal, in the navigation pane, click CDN.
>
> On the ribbon, click New. In the New dialog, select App Services, then CDN, then Quick Create.

So I'm searching for CDN in the left-hand pane but don't see it anywhere. Am I crazy?

A screenshot of the nav pane I see is below:

[image]

For good measure, I went to the New --> App Services and attempted to find CDN, but it doesn't appear to be there either:

[image]

What gives? Is there any availability for this in the new portal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create CDN in Windows Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286445/how-to-create-cdn-in-windows-azure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooops, I see I missed a related SO question: [How to create CDN in Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286445/how-to-create-cdn-in-windows-azure?rq=1)

Looks like the functionality is not available for all users, though it is documented as if it is. Bummer.

I'll move to close this question as related.