# How to configure Azure CDN now?

Tags: azure

Few years ago, when i first saw Azure, i found good feature for me: CDN.

How to configure CDN now? (In past, we needed to go previous potal and configure cdn on it).

Thanks.

Comment: All links referencing to MSarticles, where configuration requiring jump to previous portal. No chance to do that now.

Comment: Ok then refer to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286445/how-to-create-cdn-in-windows-azure, second result in Google :)

Comment: This is a duplicate question, as @abatishchev discovered. That said: CDN is now available again. I posted relevant info on the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is currently under closed preview and only available to customers who have already used in the past and have active CDN nodes condigured.

My believe is that this feature will soon be available to all Windows Azure customers.

So, as of today (05th of March 2014) Azure CDN is not available to all the customers. More information can be found [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-how-to-use/). Note that text explicitly mentions "Existing CDN customers".